# Lambda functions for filtering lists using Streams

Tags: java, arraylist, lambda, java-stream

How would I filter through a list of strings and get the first character of each string and add it to my list l using streams? "words" is my ArrayList of words which I will be calling this function on.

```
ArrayList<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
        l = (ArrayList<String>) words.stream().filter((String w)-> 
         w.substring(0,1)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return l;
```

Comment: Just change `filter` to `map`. And don't cast the result to ArrayList. Either use it as a List, or specify the implementation via `toCollection(ArrayList::new)`.

Comment: @shmosel can you tell me what does map does? I thought map assigned a key to a certain value.

Comment: It converts from one value to another. `filter()` excludes items from the stream.

Comment: @Jeff,  don't relate java collection map with stream map function. stream map function is a producer function which takes an object and turns into another object. for example: in my answer it takes String object and it turns into Character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use map instead filter. map is a producer function and will return first character from current string variable.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("amit", "shah", "pren");
List<Character> result = list.stream().map(l -> l.charAt(0)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```